# Can't add directive as plugin in Nuxt application

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to incorporate the `Ripple` package into my `Nuxt` application.

Following [Nuxt docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/) and the package [docs example](https://github.com/PygmySlowLoris/vue-ripple-directive) I have a `ripple.js` file in `plugins/` directory containing this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Ripple from 'vue-ripple-directive'
Vue.directive('ripple', Ripple)
```

Then in `nuxt.config.js` I have:

```
plugins: [
  '~/plugins/ripple.js'
],
```

But now the app doesn't work at all, with some `Unexpected token export` error message on the screen, and a "Missing stack frames" error message in `vm.js`.

[image]

I have no idea what that means nor what I'm doing wrong, any suggestion?

Comment: You can check my solution right here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60544698/solved-add-vue-directives-in-nuxt-client-side-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to an SSR error, where vue-ripple-directive cannot be used on the server.  In order to get around this, you need to instruct Nuxt to only load the plugin on the client side.

To fix this, do the following **2** things:

First, rename `ripple.js` to `ripple.client.js`.

Second, update the plugins array to the following:

```
plugins: [
  '~/plugins/ripple.client.js'
]
```

The `.client` postfix signals to nuxt to only run the plugin on the client.

More information can be found [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins#name-conventional-plugin)

Always keep this method in mind when adding Vue plugins, especially when they interact with the DOM in some way.  Most that I've come across require this method to function without errors, as the DOM is unavailable on the server.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: `Plugin not found: D:\***\***\plugins\ripple.client.js`

Comment: Double check that you've renamed the plugin file to ```ripple.client.js```, and double check it's location.  That error indicates that there's something wrong with one of those.  If that does not work, check the docs on "mode" https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins#client-side-only.  It's an alternative to the method I outlined above

Comment: I hadn't renamed it (they really should specify this in the docs) as I was assuming the postfix was just a convention for Nuxt rather than an actual file name. It works now, thanks!

Comment: The post has been updated to make that clearer for anyone else who needs this